# Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, casting

```
foreach(Control c in tabAppreciation.Controls)
        {
            if(c is Button)
            {
                if((Button)c.Text.ToString()==0)
                {
                    c.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm getting this error:
Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

I wanna compare the text of each Button with something and if it matches, change the color of the button, but it seems like I'm not doing it right at all... Can someone help me please?

Comment: Check your parentheses... I think you wanted `(Button c).Text.ToString()`, and then you'd probably want to compare it to a string so `(Button c).Text.ToString() == '0'`

Comment: @Dannnno is on the right track, but he means `((Button)c)` rather than `(Button c)`

Comment: You're checking if `ToString() == 0`?  Did you mean an empty string?

Comment: @Dannnno @adv12 Yeah the correction is:  `if (((Button) c).Text.ToString() == '0')` Thanks for your help guys, didn't know the cast could be so difficult

Answer (score 5):

You could change your code to a simpler

```
foreach(Button b in tabAppreciation.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    if(b.Text=="0")
    {
       b.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

This enumerates all the controls of type Button inside the `tabAppreciation` controls collection and your loop is strongly typed so you don't need anymore the test for `Is Button`. Notice also that the `Text` property is already a string and thus applying `ToString()` makes no sense. Finally a string should be compared to a string (put the zero between double quotes not single quotes that denote a char)

**FYI:** To use `OfType<T>`, if it is not already there, you need to add a `using System.Linq;` directive at the top of in your code file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tabAppreciation
.Controls
.Select( c => c as Button )
.Where( c => c != null )
.Where( b => b.Text.ToString() == "0" )
.ForEach( b => b.BackColor = Color.Green )
;
```

Comment: Well it is like shooting a mosquito with a cannon, but nevertheless +1

Answer (score 0):

Arguable easier to read and would have made the issue behind the question less relevent.

```
foreach(Control c in tabAppreciation.Controls)
{
  Button button = c as Button
  if(button != null && button.Text == "0")
  {
    button.BackColor = Color.Green;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. If you do have button controls in the `tabAppreciation.Controls` collection, then all you need to do is compare the text (you stated in your question: `I wanna compare the text of each Button with something and if it matches`). So change your code to something like this:

```
foreach(Control c in tabAppreciation.Controls)
{
    if(c is Button)
    {
        Button button = (Button)c;
        if(button.Text=="Button text")
        {
            c.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why you check if your text equals a number. If your button text shows a number, then you need to note, that there is a difference between `"0"` and `0` - the first is of type string and the second of type int (and `'0'` is again a different type - character).

The `ToString()` method always returns a string, so it should be easy to construct the condition (rule of thumb) - both sides between a condition operator should have the same type, so after `ToString()=` it has to come a string - `"0"` or `"text ..."`.

Answer (score 0):

`(Button)c.Text.ToString()` is trying to cast the Text property into a button. That is your error. You actually don't need to cast the c object into a Button since the Text property is inherited from [ButtonBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158234%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which overrides the Text property from the Control Class. The .NET framework is smart enough to know that you mean the overridden Text property not the base one.

To access the c as a button you need to make a new button variable and set its value as c; `Button b = c as Button`.

You also don't need to call `ToString()` on a string.